# the step of charge with stripe and angular9

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, stripe-payments, checkout

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

import { StripeService, Elements, Element as StripeElement, ElementsOptions } from "ngx-stripe";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  elements: Elements;
  card: StripeElement;

  // optional parameters
  elementsOptions: ElementsOptions = {
    locale: 'es'
  };

  stripeTest: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private stripeService: StripeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stripeTest = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
    this.stripeService.elements(this.elementsOptions)
      .subscribe(elements => {
        this.elements = elements;
        // Only mount the element the first time
        if (!this.card) {
          this.card = this.elements.create('card', {
            style: {
              base: {
                iconColor: '#666EE8',
                color: '#31325F',
                lineHeight: '40px',
                fontWeight: 300,
                fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                fontSize: '18px',
                '::placeholder': {
                  color: '#CFD7E0'
                }
              }
            }
          });
          this.card.mount('#card-element');
        }
      });
  }

  buy() {
    const name = this.stripeTest.get('name').value;

  //  console.log(this.card) ;
    this.stripeService
      .createToken(this.card, { name })
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result.token) {
          // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
          // https://stripe.com/docs/charges


          this.stripeService.stripe.charges({
            amount: 1099,
            currency: 'usd',
          }).the(x => {
            console.log(x)
          })


        } else if (result.error) {
          // Error creating the token
          console.log(result.error.message);
        }
      });
  }


}
```

```html
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="buy()" [formGroup]="stripeTest">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Jane Doe">

    <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>

    <button type="submit">
      BUY
    </button>
</form>
```

I have a angular9 project that I'm using Stripe checkout. I've followed many tutorials, and I could create a token but the step of charge give me a function not found this is my code :  when I used :
 this.stripeService.charges({
            amount: 1099,
            currency: 'usd',
          }).the(x => {
            console.log(x)
          })

it give me an error **"charges" not a function** ........ 
please help me .... any idéa without use **express**

Comment: Angular is generally a frontend library. Creating charges is a backend operation that you would do on your server since it requires your private API key, not using Angular or the stripe.js library. Rather you would do it on e.g. a Node/PHP/Java etc backend server by sending the token to that server, which is why some examples will mention Express as a backend (a backend server is ultimately required to use Stripe). https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web-submit-payment

Comment: thanks for your answer , I wil try

Comment: someone help me please , I'm try every thing all the totos but not result ,, get the token it's very easy but the charges could'nt